# Named anchors working in IE but not Firefox / Chrome

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I have a named anchor situation that is working in IE but for some reason is not working in Firefox or Chrome. This set of pages is loaded within a Blogger frameset but hosted externally so I can control everything with the page's coding.

The link to the page where the issue resides is here:
http://www.gmvemsc.org/p/vdb-index.html

If you click the first link in the page titled "Main Compartment", the issue is obvious when you click on the third photo down with the tan medication boxes. Here is the code for the link:

```
<a href="epinepherine.html#pagetop"><img src="images/pouchmain2.JPG" alt="Main Compartment Contents" width="500" height="254"></a>
```

The anchor that I have just inside the body tag of the "Epinepherine" page is this:

```
<a id="pagetop"></a>
```

If you click on the photo link in IE you are taken to the top of the Epinepherine page where the named anchor resides. If you click on the photo link in Firefox or Chrome the Epinepherine page loads but the frameset stays scrolled about halfway down the page.

Is there a better way to load each page with the browser pointed to the top of the content that resides within this frame?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `#pagetop` anchor is in another frame. It is scrolled to the top, in its own frame, but the parent frame stays in scroll position.

You should try something like this:

```html
<!-- this goes to the <head> of the <iframe> -->
<script>
// give an ID to the link, so you can do this:
document.getElementById("someID").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
  // stop the link from opening (for now)
  e.preventDefault();

  // scroll to the top of the page
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  // manually open the link
  window.location = e.target.href;
});
</script>
```

Tell me if it's working!

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been able to make that work. I tried adding the script inside the head tag of both the "pouchmain.html" file and the "epinepherine.html" file, and calling the "someID" tag. So far it has not caused the desired behavior.

Comment: Yepp, please try `window.parent.scrollTo(0, 0);`!

Comment: I just changed the script as suggested but no luck.
The changes are live here:
http://www.gmvemsc.org/p/vdb-index.html

Comment: You have to assign an ID to the link you click on, unless the script does not run at all. Change this: `<a href="epinepherine.html#someID">` to this: `<a id="someID" href="epinepherine.html">`!

Comment: I changed the link as suggested but no luck. Here is what the code looks like:
<p align="center"><a id="someID" href="epinepherine.html"><img src="images/pouchmain2.JPG" alt="Main Compartment Contents updated" width="500" height="254"></a></p>

Pointed to this:
// give an ID to the link, so you can do this:
document.getElementById("someID").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
  // stop the link from opening (for now)
  e.preventDefault();

  // scroll to the top of the page
  window.parent.scrollTo(0, 0);

  // manually open the link
  window.location = e.target.href;
});